# Upgraded to ubuntu 19.04 from 18.1, terminal won't open, python issues

Tags: python, 18.10, 19.04, python3

I recently attempted to update to ubuntu 19.04 from ubuntu 18.10, it completed but with errors. I have removed nvidia graphics card and i'm attempting to fix the install but to no avail.
I cannot open terminal, I believe the main problems are due to python issues.
I can access tty, and have attempted to reinstall python packages, this doesn't seem to work.
I get error messages such as No module named "lsb_release", "distro_info", "apt_pkg" etc.
I have tried the following commands but they now execute with no error messages;

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

I'm not exactly sure what is broken, but if for example I try to add the graphics drivers repository;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
File "usr/bin/add-apt-repository"......
No module named 'softwareproperties'
```

If I open python3.5, lsb_release, softwareproperties, distro_info all import fine, but are not there in python3.7, which is the system default for python3.

Terminal will open if i'm in files and right click for open terminal here, but not if I select it from desktop or ctrl-alt-t.

Running whereis python returns;

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python /etc/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/share/python /home/mark/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m /home/mark/anaconda3/bin/python /home/mark/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m-config /home/mark/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 /home/mark/anaconda3/bin/python3.7-config /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Comment: Please paste the full and exact output and error messages you get for each of the commands you tried, if possible. Also alternatively to gnome-terminal or the TTY, you might try `xterm` as terminal emulator. That one should not depend on Python and work regardless.

Comment: Welcome to AU! “update (…) completed but with errors” – which ones exactly? “the following commands (…) didn't work” – how exactly didn’t they work, what output and errors did you receive? Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: How about `apt-get update` -- does that work without error messages?